# LoadDocument by query in RavenDB index

Tags: ravendb

I have the following structure:

```
public class Order
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to export all customers (RavenDB Stream) with order turnover and last ordered date.
I do already have an index (`Customers_ByTurnover`) which outputs this data (map=Orders, reduce by CustomerId). Although this does only list customers which have already ordered something.

I need an index for all Customers and load these details into each row.
Here is the code I want to write (the `Query` method is pseudo and doesn't really exist):

```
public class Customers_ByOrders : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Customer, Customers_ByOrders.Result>
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Turnover { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? LastOrderedDate { get; set; }
    }

    public Customers_ByOrders()
    {
        Map = items => items.Select(item => new Result()
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            Name = item.Name,
            Turnover = Query<Order>().Where(x => x.CustomerId == item.Id).Sum(x => x.Amount),
            LastOrderedDate = Query<Order>().Where(x => x.CustomerId == item.Id).Select(x => x.CreatedDate).OrderByDescending(x => x).FirstOrDefault()
        });
    }
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create a query inside an index, to get the desired info you will have to create a [map-reduce index](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/Csharp/studio/database/indexes/create-map-reduce-index#create-map-reduce-index) on the `Orders` collection, group by on `CustomerId` and in the reduce function apply `Sum()` on `Amount` field and order the `LastOrderedDate`. To get the `Name` name field you will have to use [LoadDocument](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/csharp/indexes/indexing-related-documents#indexes-indexing-related-documents) extension.

```
public class Customers_ByOrders : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Orders, Customers_ByOrders.Result>
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Turnover { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? LastOrderedDate { get; set; }
    }

    public Customers_ByOrders()
    {
                Map = orders => from o in orders
                                   select new Result
                                   {
            Id = o.CustomerId,
            Turnover = o.Amount,
            LastOrderedDate = o.CreatedDate
        };
                        Reduce = results => from result in results
                                    group result by result.Id 
                                    into g 
                                    select new Result
                                    {
                                      Id = g.Key,
                                      Turnover = g.Sum(x => x.Turnover),
                                      LastOrderedDate = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastOrderedDate).Select(x => x.LastOrderedDate).FirstOrDefault()
                                    };
    }
}
```